# Predicate string comparison using >= and <=

Tags: cocoa, core-data, nspredicate

I have dates stored in strings (ok, i know, don't ask why.... it simply needs to be this way)

like 
20110111
20110214
... etc

i want to use the <= in predicate to compare 20110111 with 20110214

but

```
NSPredicate * predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(next <=[c] %@)", [[NSDate new] YYYYMMDDstringFromDate]];
```

yelds a

```
2012-03-16 17:52:05.236 ---[10851:11903] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid predicate: nil RHS'
```

after changing to ==[c] it works, but i want to use the <= operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your form of storage, you could directly convert them to integers and compare them as integers.  This only works since you appear to be storing them in year month day form (i.e. most significant first).  Is there a reason you don't store them as (32 bit) integers?

Comment: yes, storing as integers (NSNumber) was the solution... so i can use the < > operators... btw. how would i cast in predicate? would such cast from string to nsnumber work?

Comment: I'm not aware of there being a way of doing it in a predicate.  Getting from a string to NSNumber requires using integerValue or intValue on the string, and then that as an argument to numberWithInt(eger) - which could be done in a block of a comparator, but I'm not sure how to do it in a predicate.  And it would be ugly.